# Securing Windows 7 using Bluetooth

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I'm thinking of using my iPhone as a device combined with a low power bluetooth usb key. So when the phone is gone the workstation locks. (I don't want it to unlock the workstation though, I'd prefer if the workstation only unlocked if the phone was in range (there is a backup account of course))

However how best can I security the bluetooth stack on Windows against attacks, eg. EMET?

No data should be transferred between the phone and my computer I won't be using the Bluetooth for anything bar just seeing if the device is in range.

Yes I'm aware you can spoof the device

Comment: What is it you want specifically? The ability to use a bluetooth device (like your phone) to lock the computer when it leaves? What kinds of attacks do you want to secure the stack from? You acknowledge that devices can be spoofed, so the other thing that might need to be secured is the data, but you also acknowledge that you don't need to transmit data for this scenario. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I'd like to use my phone so when I leave my desk but accidentally forget to lock it, it will lock because the phone is out of range. I'm trying to protect against these types of flaws: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-053

Comment: I have noticed that Rohos can use RFID tokens for a simlar thing, in my testing my phone didn't work so well sadly. (Just a note for in 2 years from now when someone Googles this page and needs help)

Answer (score 2):

http://btprox.sourceforge.net/ has some code that does this. It is an application you can install that I believe is what you're looking for.

Comment: >However how best can I security the bluetooth stack on Windows against attacks, eg. EMET?

Comment: Microsoft EMET doesn't really apply here, it should be compatible with BTProx.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @ScottPack While I understand what you're saying in general, (give him the answer, not a link to the answer) I fail to see how to better supply a more direct answer in this case. I presume that he's looking for something that will allow him to lock his machine when he walks away. The application I linked to does precisely that. I didn't say "If you do this google search, you can find things like that" I essentially said "you can install this application." Should I include the source code here? A copy of the executable to host here? No, go get it at the source. That link is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the [Blackberry Smartcard reader](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2195/396) could do this for you, possibly with some 3rd party code.  I have not tried it myself, but am very interested if you get this to work in combination with the benefits of a smartcard reader

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to use a normal smart code reader?

Comment: A normal smart card reader has a physical connection to the PC.  If you want to share your SMIME or other PKI keys between multiple devices (phone, laptop, tablet) this should allow you to walk away from your PC and make it lock